# Printing from iOS Application using CUPS

Tags: ios, cups

Has anyone tried printing using CUPS from iOS/Objective-C application?

I have an iOS application that is printing on 1 POS printer from multiple devices and when printer is busy, I am having issues. I am thinking I can build a print server in Linux using CUPS and send print request from all iOS devices to a common print server.

Any ideas/suggestions on the approach? I have setup EPSON T88v Printer on Linux Box and CUPS is working fine. Now from iOS will it be AirPrint or some other way to send request to the CUPS printer.

Comment: If you want to use the in-built printing capabilities of iOS you need to use AirPrint to your queue.  Otherwise you can open a TCP connection the CUPS service and send the data directly.  If you have a Mac that you can use you can also look at PaperCut.com

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide some direction how can I open TCP connection from iOS to CUPS service? Will it be opening a TCP socket in Objective C?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on if the POS system is using the IOS printing api or it is sending directly to a printer over a tcp connection.
If it is using the IOS Printing API you can print to it from the app.

You can print from an iPad to a cups printer directly. The cups printer has to be discoverable and shared on the network (cups configuration). To verify that your cups printer is functioning correctly I would try to print from notes on the iPad to the newly created printer. If that is functioning than you can try the POS system. I would guess that the POS system is printing directly to the printer through a tcp connection using the proprietary esc/pos language in which case you will not be able to redirect it to a cups printer.